# Can't install Ubuntu under Windows 7 using Wubi?

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I am new to linux. I want help related to my dell laptop on which I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS within Windows 7.

The problem happens when I select the option in installer to ****Install ubuntu 12.04 within win7**** , after selecting this option the installer closes and command prompt massage appears showing "**Attempting to terminating everything"** then my cd drive is opens and the installation is closes.

I have 500 gb hardisk.

Answer (score 0):

May be your Wubi installer file will be corrupted or some files may be missing from Ubuntu ISO, you should also check whether you are setting the options in Wubi installer correctly, i mean proper disk size etc.I think the problem  is with  your installation media.